# iOS animate partial cells to show full cell

Tags: objective-c

I've got an UITableViewCell with a UITextField in it. When I click the UITextField I want to make sure the entire cell is visible in the tableView. I did this in textfieldDidBeginEditing, like so:

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(id)textField {
    TTTableViewCell *cell = (TTTableViewCell *)[self.tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:objc_getAssociatedObject(textField, kIndexPathId)];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y - self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight) animated:YES];
}
```

This works perfectly when the user goes down the list. Expect when to user taps a cell which is partial visible on the top it doesn't reveal the entire cell just moves a bit.

Does someone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are UITableView methods to solve exactly this. You can use [scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath%3aatScrollPosition%3aanimated%3a) to ask the table view to bring a cell to the top by passing `UITableViewScrollPositionTop`.

(You might first want to check if it's already visible to ensure it doesn't scroll unnecessarily.)